# In VSCode, after I search (cmd+f), how do I make the escape key (2x) not jump back to where I started?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, my cursor is at point P1 initially. If I search for some other text using Cmd+f, then hit escape, it will focus the text editor, but not clear the selections.

If I press escape a second time, it will clear the selections **and** move my cursor back to P1.

How do I change this behavior? I'd like to deselect the findings, but keep my cursor where it is.

Comment: Try setting `"editor.find.cursorMoveOnType": true`? That said, I can't reproduce the behaviour you're getting where you need to press escape twice with your current setings to go back to P1. Can you create a [mre]'s settings.json and keybindings.json files?

Comment: Upon further investigation, it looks like it only occurs with the vi extension enabled. Disabling the "extensions.vim_escape" keybinding (mapped to escape) removes this behavior, but also makes it impossible to go from insert mode to command mode. I'll post an issue on the relevant GitHub.